# What is the work done by gravity on a slope?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, energy, work

This is a “sequel” to [my previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/600738/what-is-the-work-done-by-gravitational-force-when-you-lift-an-object) which I asked recently.

According to my the answer should be -mgh because work= force* displacement and in this case force is mg and displacement is equal to height is this answer right or wrong.

Please let me know and if this wrong I would appreciate it if someone could correct me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup! Now matter how you change the height, the potential energy change depends only on the final states. What's special in this case compared to the one previously is that this time you don't need any external forces, it will slide down on it's in the absence of forces such as friction.